# I'm having Problems Updating BLOB on my mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently doing a database system for uni as my project for Finals, I've made inserting records to a table quite fine, and I included an image/BLOB component to the record. Inserting these with the BLOB field(I used LongBlob) went smoothly but I added another button in which supposedly updates the fields and the image. It updates the fields but not the image and I'm actually clueless as to what to do next.

This is the code for the update button:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String fName = jTextField1.getText();
    String mName = jTextField2.getText();
    String lName = jTextField3.getText();


    if(fName.equals("") || mName.equals("") || lName.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All fields must have value!");

    }else {
        try{

            eventconUrl cUrl = new eventconUrl();
            String connectionUrl= cUrl.conUrl();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            String sql = "UPDATE `castbl` SET `firstName`='"+jTextField1.getText()+"',`middleName`='"+jTextField2.getText()+"',`lastName`='"+jTextField3.getText()+"' WHERE profId = '"+jLabel7.getText()+"'";

            PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            prest.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Updated");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(addeventFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(addeventFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

    }// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Originally, I was gonna try updating it by using this:

(Updated) I tried doing this instead but I still ended up with an SQL error saying:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
String sql = "UPDATE `castbl` SET `firstName`='"+jTextField1.getText()+"',`middleName`='"+jTextField2.getText()+"',`lastName`='"+jTextField3.getText()+"',`profPic`='"+jLabel5.getIcon()+"' WHERE profId = '"+jLabel7.getText()+"'";

PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);

prest.executeUpdate();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Updated");
```

but it only updates the fields and says there's an SQL error.
Anyone have thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Oh my. Put the database code in a separate class from your UI code. And you're completely missing the point of prepared statements, which is to safely pass parameters to a query: update foo set a = ?, b = ? where c = ?. Finally, when there is an error, the very first and most important thing to do is to read the error.

Comment: I removed the misuse of prep statement and VALUES and changed the sql string but it still has an error which is stated above(I updated the question)

Comment: **USE PREPARED STATEMENTS WITH PLACEHOLDER VALUES**. This will absolutely fix your problem. This code is riddled with [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and has no hope of working if you're dealing with binary data. That **must** be escaped.

Comment: You're still not passing parameters correctly. Read my previous comment. Read the tutorial about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering but here's what I did:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String fName = jTextField1.getText();       
    String mName = jTextField2.getText();
    String lName = jTextField3.getText();


    if(fName.equals("") || mName.equals("") || lName.equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All fields must have value!");

    }else {
    try{

        eventconUrl cUrl = new eventconUrl();
        String connectionUrl= cUrl.conUrl();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        String sql = "UPDATE `castbl` SET `firstName`= ?,`middleName`= ?,`lastName`= ?,`profPic`= ? WHERE profId ='"+jLabel7.getText()+"'";
        PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
           fName = jTextField1.getText();
           prest.setString(1,fName);

           mName = jTextField2.getText();
           prest.setString(2,mName);

           lName = jTextField3.getText();
           prest.setString(3,lName);

           if(wImage.equals("No")){
           prest.setString(4, "");
           }else{
           InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(s));
           prest.setBlob(4, is);

        }
        prest.executeUpdate();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Updated"); 

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(addeventFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(addeventFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CASeditFrm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}// TODO add your handling code here:

}
```